# Determine P(M) using given statements

Tags: probability

So I have an assignment in probability.

I have the events M, A and B.

After some calculations I found that P(MAB)=0.064, P(MAB/)=0.192 and P(MA/B)=0.084.
(B/ is B complement and A/ is A complement).

My question is is there any way to determine P(M) using the given statements?

Answer (score 1):

Not just with that information, since $P(M\cap A^c \cap B^c)$ could be anything from $0$ to $0.66$

and so $P(M\cap A \cap B)+P(M\cap A \cap B^c)+ P(M\cap A^c \cap B)+ P(M\cap A^c \cap B^c)$ could be anything from $0.34$ to $1$

Comment: Thanks for the info. What about P(Mc∩Ac∩Bc)?

Comment: @DavidDaniels $1-\left(P(M^c\cap A \cap B)+P(M^c\cap A \cap B^c)+ P(M^c\cap A^c \cap B)+ P(M^c\cap A^c \cap B^c)\right)$ would work too, but you do not know any of those